# need help with integration of the form a^2+y^2

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometric-integrals

Could someone explain why 
$$\int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{169+y^2}}}=\ln|{\frac{\sqrt{169+y^2}}{13}+\frac{y}{13}}|+C$$
shouldn't it be 
$$\int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{169+y^2}}}=\ln|y+\sqrt{169+y^2}|+C$$

The reason why i believe it should be the second one is because in the calculus book i have they have the following rule
$$\int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+x^2}}}=\ln|x+\sqrt{a^2+x^2}|+C$$
or could it be both

Comment: $\sqrt{a^2+a^2}$?

Comment: fixed it . Its should have been $\sqrt{a^2+x^2}$

Comment: You have lost track of the arbitrary constant.$\ln|\frac {\sqrt {169+y^2}}{13} + \frac {y}{13}| +C = \ln|\sqrt {169+y^2} + y| - \ln {13} + C= \ln|\sqrt {169+y^2} + y|+D$

Comment: the difference between the two is a constant. I am thus led to believe that either works as an antiderivative

Comment: derivate $\ln |y+\sqrt{169+y^2}|$ and check if you get $\frac{1}{\sqrt{169+y^2}}$

Comment: Doug M I'm not sure where you got the $-\ln{13}$. I think Kitter is right when he said they should be the same

Comment: Kitter did not say they should be the same.  Kitter said either works, and they both do.  Remember that $\ln\frac{A}{B} = \ln A - \ln B$.  That is how DougM's $-\ln 13$ comes in.

Comment: Yes, just had a "Doh" moment. Can't believe I didn't catch that

Comment: @electro7912 yay for catching D'oh moments :)

Answer (score 0):

1) You need no absolute value, because $\sqrt{a^2+x^2}\ge\sqrt{x^2}=\lvert x\rvert$, so  $x+\sqrt{a^2+x^2}\ge x+\lvert x\rvert\ge0$.
2) The denominator  is part of the integration constant.

Additionally, the answer can *also* be written as
$$\frac1a\operatorname{Argth}\Bigl(\frac xa\Bigr).$$